# Why i cant access model error after rendering template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have a vilatator in Message model and it works well from the console, but after rendering a template i cant show any errors.
My routes

```
resources :rooms do
  resources :messages
 end
resources :users
```

My :new layout file

```
<h1>New Message</h1>
<%= @message.errors.messages[:body] %>
<%= render 'form', message: @message %>

<%= link_to 'Back', room_messages_path %>
```

_form file

```
<%= form_with(model: message, url: room_messages_path(params['room_id'], 
 message) ) do |form| %>
 <% if message.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(message.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this message from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
     <% message.errors.messages.each do |message| %>
       <li><%= message %></li>
     <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

 <div class="field">
   <%= form.label :body %>
   <%= form.text_area :body %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= form.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

And code in my controller

```
def create
p message_params
@message = Message.new(message_params)
@message.room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
@message.user = @current_user
respond_to do |format|
  if @message.save
    format.html { redirect_to room_message_path(@message.room, @message), notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created }
  else
    p @message.errors
    format.html { render :action => :new }
    format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:body)
end
```

I can see message errors in controller, but i can't show them in layout file.

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f5525181100 @base=#<Message id: nil, body: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 7, room_id: 3>, @messages={:body=>["can't be blank"]}, @details={:body=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

I don't know why it works in such strange way, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`full_messages`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages) instead of iterating over all error instances manually:

Change

```
<% message.errors.messages.each do |message| %>
  <li><%= message %></li>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<% message.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <li><%= message %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It still not work, I can see errors if I will puts @message.errors.messages[:body] in console inside template, but when I am trying to render it, it doesn't show

Comment: Wait, you use only message instead of @message in your view. Do you reassign the variable somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're shadowing `message` variable:

```
 <% message.errors.messages.each do |message| %>
   <li><%= message %></li>
 <% end %>
```

Try to rename it

```
 <% message.errors.messages.each do |err_message| %>
   <li><%= err_message %></li>
 <% end %>
```